# Union of a power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement true?

---

Let $A$ be a set and let $P(A)$ be the power set of A. Let $x$ be arbitrary and suppose $x \in A$.

Then $x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in \cup P(A)$.

---

Intuitively I want to say that this true, because the union of a power set of A will contain all the elements of A. But I got marked down for this on a test so I'd like to check. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer looks right to me. Perhaps you were marked down because you didn't turn your correct  intuition into a correct proof. To get more information here, [edit] the question to show us exactly what you said in your answer, and anything else you can about the grading rubric.

Comment: In fact the union of the power set of a set is the original set itself, so yes, it's true. Depending on what type of math class you're in, this fact might be 1) considered obvious and requiring no proof, 2) considered true but requiring some proof, or 3) considered true but an unnecessary diversion from a simpler proof. Or maybe even 4) possibly true depending on which axioms of set theory one uses. It could be helpful to ask your grader/instructor which view they take.

Comment: Personally, I find it odd that you would demand $x\in A$ as a hypothesis and then state your thesis as "$x\in A$ is equivalent to something else".

Answer (score 1):

If x in A, then {x} in P(A), x in $\cup$P(A).

If x in $\cup$P(A), then exists K in P(A) with x in K, x in A.